# IMPORTHTML in Google Sheets to import table with multiple pages

Tags: html, google-sheets, web-scraping

I'm trying to import a table from a website into Google Sheets using IMPORTHTML. The table has multiple pages to click through but the URL doesn't change so I can't use an array. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As you have provided partial information, and I too don't have enough reputation to ask you in the comments. So, giving you some solutions from my own research.

I found this URL with intense research which is similar to your situation. (Pls tell me what is your URL to see where is the issue)
http://trafficcrow.com/blog-commenting-sites-list/

Try to use formula (without table number) `=IMPORTHTML("http://trafficcrow.com/blog-commenting-sites-list/", "table")`.

If not solved, check if the formula is 100% correct.
When I use this formula `=IMPORTHTML("https://trafficcrow.com/blog-commenting-sites-list/", "table", 1)`

It gives perfect results by fetching all data.

**if Still not solved**

1. Ultimately, you have to copy and paste all data, if you want live then you have to go with **Excel and Import from web**, it works well.
   Search on youtube how to import data from web to excel.
2. To find what is the inner cause, the URL is needed which you haven't told yet. Will be happy to solve your problem.